# Intersect and Trim lines with a polygon

Tags: algorithms

I have defined a `Polygon`. I want to intersect and trim a list of other `Lines` with the `Edges` of this polygon (white rectangle here), so that endpoints of lines are limited to the inner part of the polygon.

currently, I'm intersecting each cyan line with the edges of the polygon which gives me the intersection points. But the problems is I don't know how to trim them. I know that I need to change the `X1`, `Y1`, `X2` and `Y2` of each intersecting line (cyan line) to the intersection point. But I don't know how do do it.

Let me explain it this way. A cyan line intersects one of the edges of the polygon, now I need to move the endpoint of the cyan line to the intersection point to simulate a trim right? **Which endpoint** I need to move? I'm a bit lost here.

```
public class Polygon
{
    public List<Line>() Edges;
}

public class Line
{
    public double X1;
    public double X2;
    public double Y1;
    public double Y2;
}

var listOfIntersectingLines = new List<Line>() {L1, L2, ... };

var ListOfLinesLimitedToPolygon = ?
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's one simple approach: for each line in the polygon, define which side is inside and which side is outside.  For each intersection point, use this information to define which side of the intersection is inside/outside.  Finally, travel along the line and create new line segments for each pair of points inside the polygon until you reach the end.

Comment: @yters Thanks ytres, unfortunately I couldn't understand this well. How can I define which side is inside and which side is outside? As it is shown in the first image, some lines have both ends outside of the polygon. My problem is say one of these lines intersects an edge. Now how would I know which end of the intersecting line I need to move to the intersection point.

Comment: With your line class, you need an integer variable called "inside".  Then, when you create your polygon, for each line set "inside" to -1 if the left side of the line (going from X1,Y1 to X2,Y2) is inside, and 1 if the right side of the line is inside.  Now when another line intersects a polygon side, you can say which side of the intersection is inside, and which side is outside.  (NOTE - when constructing the polygon you'll need to manually specify which side of each line is inside/outside)  Hopefully that's a bit clearer, it's all I can do for now.

Comment: Thanks ytres, that is actually enlightening me on some other geometrical problems I have got.

Comment: Representing a polygon as a list of lines is not a good idea. Use a list of points, instead. This reduces storage space by 50% and guarantees that there are no gaps.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about " moving" end points. Take a given cyan line, and intersect it with the edges of the polygon. If the polygon is convex, there will be two intersection points. These two points are the end-points of the trimmed version of the cyan line.

If the polygon is not convex, there will be an even number ($n$) of intersection points, where $n \ge 2$. Sort these intersection points (by increasing $x$ value, for example). Then, taken in pairs, they give you the end-points of the segments of the cyan line that lie inside the polygon.

Comment: Thanks bubba, `If you really want to think in terms of "moving" points ... the end-point you should move is the one that's closer to the intersection point you just found` I don't think this part is a good idea, because as you can see in the image above it will result in erroneous results for the lines close to top-left and bottom-right vertices.

Comment: True. I deleted that part of the answer.